# FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT(No such file or directory) when change target from 21 to 26

Tags: java, android

I developed an Android App with API 21 as target SDK version.
I saved downloaded file on memory. then in new release version, I updated my app with target SDK version 26 And save downloaded file on Android /data /com.xxx/file/folder. on new version. 
Everything works fine when the user deny the storage permission on the old version(Target 21) and downloads the file. But when it comes to updating to a new version(Target 26) and trying to download it, this problem happens:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx/file/aghati.tmp: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
 public DownloadFileFromURL(Context _mContext) {
    super(_mContext, R.layout.dialog_download_page);
    isCompleted = false;
    _PatchSave=getPathOfSaveFile();
    setMatchFile(_PatchSave, _NameFile, _passOFFile);

    saveFile(patchSaveTMP);

}


public File getPathOfSaveFile(Context mContext) {

        file = mContext.getExternalFilesDir(null);

    if (!file.exists())
        file.mkdirs();

    return file;
}

private void setMatchFile(String _PatchSave, String _NameFile, String _passOFFile) {
    patchSaveTMP = _PatchSave;

    File file = new File(patchSaveTMP);
     file.mkdirs();
    String nameFile = "/" + _NameFile;

    patchSave = patchSaveTMP + nameFile + "." + _passOFFile;
    patchSaveTMP = patchSaveTMP + nameFile + ".tmp";

}
```

Comment: You said you downloaded to ..../Android /data /com.xxx/file/folder. Then where does /mnt/sdcard come from in this story? Just download to .../Android /data /com.xxx/file/folder and you will be fine.

Comment: @blackapps I edited the question. please check again.

Comment: @blackapps he said some user, after update to new version with SDK version 26, could not download on /Android /data /com.xxx/file/folder and get java.io.FileNotFoundException exception.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx/file/aghati.tmp` Unclear what this path is. Is it a path to a folder aghati.tmp? Or should aghati.tmp be a file in folder '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx/file'? If the latter: does folder ''/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xxx/file' exist? Did you check before you tried to download? You have a /file folder. Normally you would have a /files folder there. Why is the s failing?

Comment: @blackapps aghati.tmp a file in "file" folder.
But when I on and off the storage permission , problem solved.

Comment: And does that folder exist before download? I asked that before.

Comment: @blackapps I'm not checking for the folder exist  or not , but from the file.mkdirs () method I use.

Comment: file.mkdirs() returns true or false. If it returns false the folder is not created. Are you checking the return value? Dont continu if it is false. Only call mkdirs() if the folder does not exist. So check that first.

Comment: @blackapps sometimes return true But after rest device , return false.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @blackapps  When new install app(Target 26) ,no problem.